# Flutter fails on Gradle error: Execution failed for task

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, gradle

working on the project with Flutter, and then adding to my code firebase to have a link to the database got an error.
Try to change the version in Gradle dependencies and other solutions, but it seems not working for me.
Maybe is it a new solution for that?

Error message added below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
    > Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
       > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
          > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported
```